How can I fetch worker node and driver node config and identify a UDF is not running on the same driver node?
Problem Statement: I have a PySpark UDF which makes a gRPC call to an external API. I have n workers in Databricks cluster, and the code submits m (=n) number of UDFs to make these gRPC calls in m/n no of iterations (code submits n UDF for processing per iteration). How would I know if all worker nodes have one UDF to process at one time. Or how can I equally distribute n UDFs across the cluster having n worker nodes?
Any suggestion or help would be a great assist?

Can you show some sample data and UDF

Jonathan, overall it looks like;
def make_grpc_call(batch_id):
# make grpc call and fetch the response
@udf(returnType=StringType)
def submit_grpc_requests(batch_id):
# call make_grpc_call for each batch_id.

Each batch consists millions of records.
